# How to create a rails project using rails/master (beta 4.0.0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

How can I create a rails project using [rails/master](https://github.com/rails/rails)?

`rails new app_name --edge` uses Rails 3.2.8 and points to the '3-2-stable' branch in the Gemfile.

Creating a rails project, pointing `gem 'rails'` to master and running `bundle` or `bundle install` generates several errors. I am also weary of this approach because the `rails new` command for each version can vary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just download the head from github and run it from there:

```
$ gem update bundler #unless you've got 1.2 already

$ git clone https://github.com/rails/rails.git
$ ruby rails/railties/bin/rails new fooapp --dev
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0.beta
```

Or for more recent versions of rails, use the `exe` directory instead:

```
$ ruby rails/railties/exe/rails new fooapp --dev
```

It's also worth noting that the `--dev` will generate a `Gemfile` pointing to your local copy of Rails. If you instead want it to point at the current copy on github use `--edge`.

Comment: +1 It took me a lot more work on the Gemfile but you got me started! Thanks @sunkencity!

Comment: what work did you have to do on the Gemfile @Dru? I'm trying to do the same thing as yourself\

Comment: Hey Stephen, I posted on my site about this: Check it out http://www.drurly.com/blog/2012/09/08/create-a-rails-4-project/

Comment: Is it still the best way? Cloning `rails.git` takes forever.

Comment: Newer versions of rails have the executable in `rails/railties/exe/rails` instead of ruby `rails/railties/bin/rails`